# Web app idea directions

Tags: api, web-applications, mashup

I have an idea for a web app project, however, due to not having any programming knowledge, I'm first asking here for directions. Essentially, I wonder if the idea is realistic and what the most effective way could be for me to tackle it.

I want to combine several open-data sources, some in the form of API's (e.g. Google maps), others in the form of statistics in Excel sheets. Like a Mashup of different sources? The idea is to use the data to perform some data crunching and in effect provide some insights from this data in an aggregated way. I have previously played around with dashboards during an internship and I am attracted by the idea to maybe produce a Single page application for my idea with some visualisation. Any thoughts on this?

I have looked at the following services online, but I have no idea if they can help me produce a web app which aggregates different data sources and that allows for nice presentation:

Zoho Creator,
QlikSense,
Sproutcore, 
Caspio

Any thoughts on this are highly appreciated!

Best regards

Comment: I'd tackle something a little more manageable as a first project.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re not a developer and would like to get started immediately, then you could get started by signing up with Zoho Creator. Its intuitive yet easy to use builder lets you setup web app in minutes.

Regarding your query for aggregation from different data sources, Zoho Creator provides REST API that allows you to access external data sources to interface with your web applications.

Zoho Creator allows you to setup the perfect web-app on a secure cloud with admin level access to handle the necessary permissions and manage data.

You can customize the Reports in your Zoho Creator application using Report Settings to suit your needs. Web-App can be created by converting a CSV/Excel into a full-featured Web DB / app in seconds.

You can check out our [help videos](https://www.zoho.com/creator/help/getting-started/quick-start-guide.html) or register for our upcoming [webinar](https://www.zoho.com/creator/webinars.html) to know more about Zoho Creator.

Happy Building!!

*Disclaimer: I work for Zoho Creator*